# cabal sandbox dependencies not found

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

I have a problem when I work with cabal sandbox, I created a sandbox  for a 'hello world' application but when I try to run `cabal install --only-dependencies` I get the following error:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
Resolving dependencies... cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: haskeline-0.7.2.1/installed-dad... (user goal) next goal:
helloworld (user goal) rejecting: helloworld-0.1.0.0 (conflict:
haskeline => base==4.7.0.2/installed-918..., helloworld => base>=4.8
&& <4.9) Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have
consistent dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending
packages or recreating the sandbox.
```

I want to mention that if I try to run on this sandbox *cabal repl* I get the error.

```
$ cabal repl
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If
this fails, please run configure manually. Resolving dependencies...
Configuring helloworld-0.1.0.0... cabal: At least the following
dependencies are missing: base ==4.8.*
```

If I run cabal repl outside of sandbox everything is working ok.

If any of you have an idea pls share with me :),

thanks
sorin

Comment: fix it, change on helloworld.cabal at  **build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.9**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your version constraints want you to use GHC 7.10- which bundles base version 4.8- while you're using GHC 7.8 and base 4.7. You could:

- Modify the cabal file and its base version bounds
- Switch to a different version of GHC
- Try building with [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack#readme), which will automatically detect those kinds of things during stack init and then offer to install the appropriate GHC for you.

Comment: you right, already change the file, thanks for your replay ;)